# Why does the official Microsoft tutorial have me push two copies of the same dotnet core app as the "frontend" and "backend"?

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, microsoft-identity-web

I'm pretty new to Azure, and I wanted to get familiar with using Azure AD auth as an authentication provider for a dotnet core web app.

I followed this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/tutorial-auth-aad?pivots=platform-linux

It worked as described, but I have to be missing something, because the way it's deployed doesn't make any sense to me.

The "starting point" tutorial code is this repo, here: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/dotnet-core-api

It's a simple dotnet core web app that hosts an Angular frontend. Through the course of the tutorial, you make some changes to get the "frontend" to talk to the "backend", and you add two remotes to your Git repo - `frontend` and `backend` - but they're *on the same repo*.

As I understand it, at the end of this tutorial, I have *two* nearly-identical Azure App Service instances running in my Azure resource group. They are both running the same code. Both include the full-stack application - both are hosting a Kestrel or HTTP.sys (or whatever) instance on port 443 at their respective `.azurewebsites.net` URL - both show my `index.html` page - but one is supposed to be the "frontend" and the other is supposed to be the "backend". The only thing different about the "frontend" and "backend" is that the "backend" has an identity provider configured, and the "frontend" has API permissions granted to it from the "frontend".

Is it really necessary to have the whole service running in both places? Is there a way to host the actual dotnet core API service as an App Service, host the HTML / JS / CSS separately as an Azure Static Page (or something similar), and still configure the identity provider? Or does it have to be like this? It seems like overkill, from a technical standpoint, as well as from a billing standpoint.

Comment: Sure, you can have a server host both and talk to itself but I think the point of the tutorial is to demo end to end auth in an app where server roles/responsibilities are distributed  (disclaimer: I only read the title) which would seem to me to be a showcase of "hey y'all, here's how you can have your one server do the auth and then share it out so all servers in the chain of delivering the app know the user is authd" .. ?

Comment: If you use the VS templates for new projects and you make a new angular app, do you get an option to add auth to the project? I ask because you do the the Blazor templates, probably the English ones would set up a hello world project for you, with auth, all running off one server/deplorable to a single app service, if you just tick the options (but I've never made an Angular project in VS)

Answer (score 0):

As @[Caius Jard](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1410664/caius-jard) mentioned, we can include both of them in a single solution. We can actually use MVC Web Application in this case where we can create a frontend in `view` and write the actual code in `control`. If we are using a core application then we can create the backend and frontend in two environments such as Angular for Frontend and .Net core for Backend and integrate them.

**REFERENCES:**

1. [Azure AD Authentication For MVC Web Application (c-sharpcorner.com)](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/azure-ad-authentication-for-mvc-web-application/#:%7E:text=%20Azure%20AD%20Authentication%20For%20MVC%20Web%20Application,it%20%E2%80%9CStartup.cs%E2%80%9D.%20The%20file%20will%20contain...%20More%20)
2. [Angular and .Net core - Azure AD authentication | The-worst.dev](https://the-worst.dev/azure-ad-authentication-for-angular-net-core-backend/)